# Cutting around obstacles in fiber cement siding

Tags: siding

I'm rebuilding a wall on my workshop.  At the top of the exterior side, I have to fit something around the ends of the rafters above the J-channel at the top of the siding (there's no soffit.)  That involves cutting 1-3/4" wide, 1-2" deep notches every 24".  I have some fiber cement siding left over from another project that I wanted to use (mostly because it's free.)  If I were using wood, I'd just use a jigsaw to cut the notches.  I've seen circular saw blades and pneumatic shears for cutting the siding, but since this is a one-off project, I really don't want to have to buy anything expensive.  How should I do this?

Comment: Carbide or diamond tip blades for your jigsaw would probably work well enough. An inexpensive set is in the $15-20 range.

Answer (score 1):

Manual fiber cement cutter (possibly hire one),  hacksaw (but it's slow), angle grinder with a diamiond wheel (slow-ish and noisy and dusty) sabre saw (slightly easier than the hacksaw, but the blades you ruin are more expensive)